What is the difference between LG TV models OLED55G46LS vs OLED55G45LW?
Can anyone advise what the difference is between these two LG TV models? They appear to be the same price and the specs seem to be the same, so I was wondering which is the better model, if they aren't exactly the same.
If there is a guide anywhere that I can read that explains why there are two different models with apparently the same specs and what those are, please let me know.


2024-2025 OLED TV Buying Guide for Europe/Australia/Asia
"1 - 55 & 65 inch Gallery OLED models have two sub models in EU
LW = NO STAND in Box | LS = has a Stand in the box
Ex. LG OLED55G4xLW or LG OLED55G4xLS where x = regional variant/identifier.
Any number after the 4 on OLED models represents a regional model that the only difference may include: Speaker Wattage, Color of Bezel/Back, or Single vs Twin Tuner."

From Reddit

On Currys website it’s saying the one with the stand has anti glare and the one with the wall mount doesn’t that’s a bit odd
